# Dates comparing not get work in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone tell me why my date is not get working.
Basically when i try to compare date then is is not working in angularJs

```
  var dateObj1 = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'); // output is "04-May-2016"
    var dateObj2 = $scope.employee.Tue; // output is "03-May-2016"
    if (dateObj1 < dateObj2) {         
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

above is working but for case below is not working if i use date as "26-Apr-2016" i get true in return

```
 var dateObj1 = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'); // output is "04-May-2016"
    var dateObj2 = $scope.employee.Tue; // output is "26-Apr-2016"
    if (dateObj1 < dateObj2) {         
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you are checking dateObj instead of dateObj1

Comment: i change the above code but still same issue

Comment: What type is dateObj2? Even when the output looks like a date, it could be a string.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [the date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), this filter

> Formats date to a string based on the requested format.

So when comparing dateObj1 to dateObj2, you are using the string comparison which is the lexicographic order.

You must parse your string to a Date (by using `Date.parse`) to obtains the wanted results

Answer (score 1):

Check out This, `Date.parse` is needed to accomplish this task

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
  var dateObj1 = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'); // output is "04-May-2016"
  var dateObj2 = Date.parse("26-Apr-2016");
  if (Date.parse(dateObj1) < dateObj2) {
    alert(true);
    return true
  }
  else {
    alert(false);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
</div>
```