# How to convert Date into Standard format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am created a Laravel AngularJs application with a search bar;used to search data between two dates.

I am created a AngularJs function in following way.

```
$scope.searchDateParticular=function()
{
    if( $scope.fromDate.toISOString)
        $scope.fromDate = $scope.fromDate.toISOString();
    if( $scope.toDate.toISOString)
        $scope.toDate = $scope.toDate.toISOString();

    $http.get('/api/accountParticularWithDate',{account_id:$scope.myAccount.id,fromDate:$scope.fromDate,toDate:$scope.toDate}).
        success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            $scope.particulars=data;
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

But,I got an error in data conversion.I need your help to convert AngularJs date into Universal format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021734/dates-comparing-not-get-work-in-angular-js/37022062#37022062 go through this answer

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you see anything in the console?

Comment: What is *$scope.fromDate*? is it a Date object?

Comment: yes $scope.froDate is a DatetimePicker object.I got some htmlcode in error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in following ways:

```
 $scope.searchDateParticular=function(fromDate,toDate)
{
    var from = $filter("date")(Date.parse(fromDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var to = $filter("date")(Date.parse(toDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    $http.get('/api/accountParticularWithDate',{params:{'account_id':$scope.myAccount.id,'fromDate':to,'toDate':from}})
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.particulars=response.data;
            getTotalStatement($scope.particulars);
            //console.log(response.data);
        });

}
```

Now the problem fixed.Thank you for your support for all.